# How to remove users as they log out using middleware

Tags: python, django, signals, middleware

I am using the middleware below to generate a list of currently logged-in users. The problem I am having is how to remove users automatically from the `online_now` and `online_now_ids` when they have logged out. I have tried to use signals but with no success...any help much appreciated

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out
#Set Environment variables for settings.py

ONLINE_THRESHOLD = getattr(settings, 'ONLINE_THRESHOLD', 30*1)
ONLINE_MAX = getattr(settings, 'ONLINE_MAX', 50)
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = getattr(settings, 'CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS', 10)

def get_online_now(self):
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=self.online_now_ids or [])


class OnlineNowMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Maintains a list of users who logged into the website.
    User ID's are available as `online_now_ids` on the request object,
    and their corresponding users are available lazzily as the `online_now`
    property on the request object
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        #Get the index 
        uids = cache.get('online-now', [])

        #multiget on individual uid keys

        online_keys = ['online-%s' % (u,) for u in uids]
        fresh = cache.get_many(online_keys).keys()
        online_now_ids = [int(k.replace('online-','')) for k in fresh]

        #if user is authenticated add id to list
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            uid = request.user.id
            #if uid in list bump to top
            # and remove earlier entry

            if uid in online_now_ids:
                online_now_ids.remove(uid)
            online_now_ids.append(uid)
            if len(online_now_ids) > ONLINE_MAX:
                del online_now_ids[0]


        #Attach modifications to the request object
        request.__class__.online_now_ids = online_now_ids
        request.__class__.online_now = property(get_online_now)

        #Set the new cache

        cache.set('online-%s' % (request.user.pk), True, ONLINE_THRESHOLD)
        cache.set('online-now', online_now_ids, ONLINE_THRESHOLD)
```

Comment: The biggest problem here is conceptual; there is just no way to tell when someone logs out, because people don't necessarily log out. They navigate to another site, or close the page, or let their computer go to sleep...

Comment: I agree with Daniel. It might be better to use web sockets to establish if the user is online (in at least some background tab)

Comment: @Daniel with SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE  set none of the above should be an issue

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. The session cookie may well have expired, but there is still no way for the server to know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets for this, otherwise it won't be REALLY showing `online` users.

Without sockets, it won't be so accurate but here is what you can do in steps:

- Create a last activity (datetime) field for the user. (OneOnOne or any way you want to store this relationship)
- In your middleware, change the code to update the last activity field of the user.

  ```
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
      user_activity, c = UserActivity.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
      user_activity.last_activity = timezone.now()
      user_activity.save()
  ```

That's all you need.

To query online users (not exact query, just an example):

```
User.objects.filter(activities__last_activity__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(seconds=30))
```